# Moved code to a new .net C# web application. Every code behind has an error 'name does not exist in the current context'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have inherited a medium-sized project (about forty .aspx and aspx.cs files) from someone who has left the company. The code was pushed to a remote git repo in a state that does not compile, does not include a readme, etc. Fun!

So, I copied the existing code files, created a new solution, new project, used Visual Studio's tool where necessary e.g. "Add to Project"->"Add existing" to add those copies to a new solution/project.

When I build this new project, I get thousands of errors, each one essentially the same: any control named in a .aspx.cs file is 'name does not exist in the current context'. So, 'txtUserName' in login.aspx.cs gets that error, even though it is plainly defined in login.aspx as '<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername"  runat="server" Columns="16" ></asp:TextBox>'.

I have changed the Project's 'Default NameSpace' in Project Properties to match the original project's name, but that had no effect. There are other similar questions on SO where a small project stopped compiling, with similar errors, out of the blue, but I haven't found any where a large project's code is moved to a new project.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Probably the old site was a Web Site Project, not a Web Application Project. You'd either need to do a new Web Site Project, or go through the conversion process so the .Designer files get created. Easiest way to convert I've found is to create new files in VS matching the names of the old files, then copy paste the code from the old project to the new one. It's tedious, but shouldn't take more than an hour to do 40 files and it only needs to be done once.

Comment: take a look at the web.config if everything is correct. What VS version are you using? Framework?

Comment: I agree with above - unzip the repository to a folder. Now from VS use open web site, and open the folder. It may well have been setup as a asp.net web site as opposed to a asp.net web site application. You can usually tell quite quick if there is no sln project file in the folder.

Comment: create new proj and for each page past the aspx code into new aspx page, save it, this should create the references in the designer files, then folow suit with copy and pasting the cs code. Try a page or 2 to see if it works. tedious but sometimes that can same you alot of time trying to figure everything out.